# How to load every tenth frame of the video using readframe?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I used function read() for load frames in mMtlab. 
I noticed NOTE: READ will be removed in the future release. Use READFRAME instead. I looked help for readframe but I do not know how to do. I use to code for read():

```
framesToRead = 1:10:numberOfFrames;
 for k=1:length(framesToRead)
   frameIdx = framesToRead(k);
   currentFrame   = read(VRef,frameIdx);

   allFrames(:,:,:,k) = currentFrame;
 end
```

Do you know how to use the readframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readFrame` by default reads single frames in your video.  You don't have a choice but to loop over all of the frames and only save every 10th frame yourself.  `readFrame` is part of the `VideoReader` framework, and to determine the total number of frames when reading in a video with `VideoReader`, we unfortunately don't have access to an easy property like `numberOfFrames` like in previous video reader tools with MATLAB.  You however have access to the total duration of the movie as well as the frame rate.

As such, you'd find the total number of frames by simply multiplying the duration of the movie and the frame rate together.  We can pre-allocate a matrix that will contain as many frames as there are if you were to save every 10th frame, then place these frames in the matrix manually at every 10th frame you encounter.

Something like this will work:

```
obj = VideoReader('...'); %// Place your video path here
width = obj.Width; %// Get width and height of the video
height = obj.Height;
numChannels = 3; %// Get number of channels.  Assuming RGB - Change if necessary
numberOfFrames = obj.Duration*obj.FrameRate; %// Calculate total number of frames to save

%// Determine total number of frames to save
totalFrames = floor(numberOfFrames/10);

allFrames = zeros(height,width,numChannels,totalFrames,'uint8'); %// Pre-allocate frames matrix

k = 0; %// Counts the total number of frames so far
count = 1; %// Keeps track of where to place frame
while hasFrame(obj)
    frm = readFrame(obj); %// Read frame
    k = k + 1; %// Increment count
    if mod(k,10) == 0 %// If we're at the 10th frame, save it
        allFrames(:,:,:,count) = frm;
        count = count + 1;
    end
end
```

The beginning of the code is self explanatory. We're simply using the properties of `VideoReader` to get the width and height of the video and I'm assuming your video is colour and 8 bits per pixel so the total number of channels is 3.  We also determine the number of frames and also the total number of frames to save.

We then pre-allocate a 4D matrix to save our frames, then we use [`hasFrame`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.hasframe.html) to check if we have any more video frames to read.  We put this into a `while` loop and use `readFrame` to read in video frames one at a time, check to see if this frame number is a multiple of 10 and if it is, place this into our frames matrix and keep going.

Now if you finally want to show the frames, something like this could work:

```
for k = 1 : size(allFrames,4)
    imshow(allFrames(:,:,:,k));
    pause;
end
```

This cycles through each frame and puts it into a figure and it pauses and waits for you to push a key.  This will go through each frame after you push a key until the end.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do you view the save frames  from a 4D matrix?

Comment: @medic911 let me update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I recommend filtering your frame sequence using `ffmpeg` . It's far more powerful and flexible than any Matlab script can be.   At the risk of tooting my own question,  you can find out how to use `ffmpeg` as a frame filter [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1024434/convert-high-speed-video-to-normal-by-subsampling-frames)

Comment: Can you combine ffmpeg with Matlab? Can it be for example in matlab choose the period in which the ffmpeg save frames?